# Whenever gem cron job error Ubuntu Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to schedule activejob with Whenever gem.

```
set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log"
every 5.minutes do
  runner 'TestJob.perform_now', :environment => 'development' 
end
```

By I get error, and don’t know how to fix it. I run project on Ubuntu system.

**error**

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can anybody help with this?

Comment: Paste complete backtrace of error.

Comment: @RAJ  /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory. This is what I get to my cron.log file.

Comment: Are you using rvm? If yes, what is the output of `rvm list`

Comment: @RAJ I'm using rbenv

Comment: Is your application running okay? Post output of `which ruby` & `whereis ruby`

Comment: Try `set :default_env, { path: "~/.rbenv/shims:~/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" }`